# How can I acces multiple parts of self object in Rust with different methods

Tags: oop, rust, borrow-checker

I am quite new to Rust. So this is my problem. I have a struct, that acts basically like a graph with depths.
So I have Vec of GraphNodes (called nodes) and Array of Vecs (called rows) which represents which graph node belongs to which depth (or row). These Vecs contain indices to the nodes Vec.

Now this is my problem

```rust
        let previous_row = self.rows.get((row - 1) as usize).unwrap();
        for node_index in previous_row {
            let node_from_previous_row = self.get_node(*node_index);
```

I ask for row from the array, that is apparently an immutable borrow of self.
Then I would like to get the node via get_node method, which is just basically a small wrapper on the nodes Vec, and the outcome has to be mutable since I want to modify it, therefore the self has to be mutable as well. But that is against the rules as it seems.

I come from C++, so my idea was to have something similar to this

```cpp
        const std::vector<int>& previous_row = rows[row - 1];
        for (int node_index : previous_row) {
            Node& node_from_previous_row = get_node(node_index);
```

What is the Rust way to do this? Is there one?

I understand that there is no guarantee that I do not completely destroy the object in the get_node method, but surely there is way how to achieve this, right?

Comment: Probably just have `get` (or better `get_mut` since you want mutable access, maybe `get_row_mut` on the whole struct is an even better place for the method) return an `Iterator<Item = &mut T>` instead of indices. Very hard to tell since your [example is not complete](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).